# java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 0 in class file

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, java-8, ubuntu-10.04

I have a war file deployed in tomcat 8.0.24, with jdk 8 and ubuntu 14.04 which works fine.

The same configuration was made, except on an old  machine with ubuntu 10.04. The  problem here is that the application fails to start with strange exception

```
01-Sep-2015 14:30:47.089 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
       org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'XXXX' defined in class path resource [spring-context.xml]: Invocation of 
init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 0 in class file YYYY
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1768)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 0 in class file XXXX
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2476)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:857)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1282)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164)
    ... 25 more
```

I got the class file that seems corrupt, but I can decompile with IntelijIdea, I can try to run it with java -cp XXX and it fails accordingly with no  main method found. I  opened the class and it has the right CAFE BABE thing at the beginning.The only difference is ubuntu versions, but I can't figure out what is causing the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: The JDK version is the same in both machines?

Comment: Is that a class file from a third party jar? If so, even one corrupt class in that jar could cause this exception to be thrown.

Comment: The class is from my code, but there are a lot of dependencies from 3rd parties, but it's a good idea to  check those. I'll give it a try

Comment: I'm guessing then that the class file got corrupted when you transferred the war or when war was exploded in the Ubuntu 10.04 machine. Best bet is to clean everything, copy the war and try again.

Comment: It is not corrupted: I copied that class form the remote server on my  local and I opened it with Intellij and it worked fine. I tried several times to clean everything,   recopied the war, I even unzipped manually the  war and copied the expanded folder into  tomcat webapps directory, but still no success. I am still shocked about this. We ended up moving forward with jdk 7, which worked,  with exactly the same war file. Maybe something wrong with jdk  8???

Comment: In your stack trace I see two occurrences of the exception, one saying "XXXX" and the other saying "YYYY". Are these the same class in the original message? If not, have you tried disassembling both?

Comment: When suspecting JDK 8 you may want to compare the behaviour of openjdk and a download directly from Oracle.